# Bootstrap's center-block not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use center-block to center the navigation of my WordPress template, which is using bootstrap. I've tried applying the `center-block` class to each and every one of these class names with no luck, the navigation items (`li` menu items) are still pulling to the left. I've also tried adding in my own custom class to replicate the `center-block` in my own `custom.css` file with no luck.

So where exactly should be putting the center-block or any other center code? I've gone through and inspected each element to try to work out which ones are not exactly being centered but I still can't put my finger on it.

```
<nav class="site-navigation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="container primary">
                <div class="col-sm-12 primary responsiveSelectContainer">
                    <ul id="menu-primary-navigation-1" class="menu responsiveSelectFullMenu">
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-2002"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/">Home</a></li>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</nav>
```

the original php and html code:

```
<nav class="site-navigation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="container primary">
                <?php wp_nav_menu(  
                    array(  
                        'menu'              => 'Primary Navigation',
                        'container'         => 'div',
                        'container_class'   => 'col-sm-12 primary'  
                        )  
                ); ?> 
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
```

Comment: center-block centers block level elements. Are you trying to center elements that are floated or set to inline-block in your CSS?

Comment: @BarryWalsh I'm trying to center the menu items of my navigation on the page. So I guess in terms of the HTML, I'm trying to center the `ul` on the page so that it is centered and not on the left of my navbar

Comment: @Morpheus Yep, it was included with Bootstrap 3. But I'm happy to use any solution really.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my initial comment by accident. Have you tried using `text-center` class instead?

Comment: @Morpheus Yep I tried this, but I'm not looking to center any text. I'm looking to center the elements within the div

Comment: You do realize you aren't using the Bootstrap grid system properly, don't you? You have a container in a container and no row. You're going to have all sorts of issues that way.

Comment: Besides not using the grid correctly, there is no centering on the navigation navbar in Bootstrap, it's left or right as per the docs. You would need to make the navigation list items inline-block and adjust a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default container primary">
```

I am not seeing where you are using some of the built in default navbar tags, which may be the reason it is not centering. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Tried this already also but didn't work. The actual div is centered perfectly fine in the middle of the page, but the content is not centered (the menu items)

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="center-block" style="width:200px;background-color:#ccc;">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I wrap the PHP menu in this `center-block` div then it successfully centers it...but only with the `style` added in too. Do you know why? Seems strange. When I remove the style the div is no longer centered

Comment: Sorry never mind, the actual `ul` items are not centered, I misjudged it for being centered as the width was only 200 so it looked centered. It doesn't work I'm afraid.